# How to log out using spring-security?

Tags: spring-security

I am applying Spring-security on my struts2 application, it perfectly works but when I am in an address like following and click on logout it runs into following error,

```
 localhost/myProject/cons
```

Error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.myProject.controller.cons.j_spring_security_logout()
```

I can only logout successfully when I am in first page (index page) of the application.
I reckon the problem is with my login link but not sure how to solve the issue.

**security.xml**

```
<logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>
```

**Logout link**

```
 <a href="<c:url value="j_spring_security_logout" />" > Logout</a>
```

Comment: You can also promote my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. I forgot to add this to the top of my page.

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

So this is what the beginning of the page will look like,

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```