# Logout in Spring Security does not work

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

I have created an application with Spring Security. In the Spring Security Context file I have added the following piece of code:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/metrics.jsp#chart" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/metrics.jsp" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_logout#chart" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/loginerror.jsp"  default-target-url="/index.jsp" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

In the application context file I have added the following code:

```
<bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
</bean>
```

In the pages of the application (I use JSP), I have added the following code for the logout button:

```
 <a href="j_spring_security_logout" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
```

Well, when the user clicks the button, he is redirected to the login page, however he can still go to other pages of the application, which should not happen, Does anyone know where the problem may be? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<a href="/j_spring_security_logout"` instead of `<a href="j_spring_security_logout"`?

Comment: @devnull, we answered in the same time :). I already answered the similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391219/how-to-log-out-using-spring-security/16391485#16391485

Comment: Guys, I have added the / symbol: still the same behavior

Comment: Have you checked you aren't viewing cached pages? And have you looked at the debug log to see what happens at each stage?

Comment: Also why are you trying to declare an intercept-url pattern for the logout URL with admin access? This will have no effect since URL fragments (after a # character) are not visible to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<a href="/j_spring_security_logout" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Servlet-context write this :

```xml
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor"class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>     
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Its same as:

```
response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");              
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
```